# Simogeo FileManager View/Upload

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, file-manager

I've tried to set up [Simogeo's FileManager](https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager) but I can only get half of it working.
My plan is to set it to a specific folder (`../imgs/gallery`) and allow the client to upload, download, rename, remove files - basically change the ones displayed on a specific page (`../gallery.html`).

Right now though, I can't get the FileManager to work properly. In it's absolutely simplest form (that is, uploading the extracted files to my `/www/` root and duplicating `filemanager.config.js.default` to `filemanager.config.js`) it will allow me to create a folder and upload files but the second I do that, it'll just keep 'loading' something. Nothing shows, nothing is usable and a refresh will completely remove it from view.

The files are being created/uploaded in the `../userfiles/` folder which I can change in the future but it's just not working even in a pure setting.

(**also**, the instructions request changing a file `../connectors/php/filemanager.config.php`, which for the life of me, I cannot find. `../connectors/php/default.config.php` exists but doesn't follow the instructions very well if I was to substitute that.)

**EDIT**: I tried the 0.8 version, having no problems. It's a shame the up-to-date one doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure permissions are set correctly on your folder ?

You could try :

```
chmod -R 0777 /path/to/filemanager/userfiles/
```

or (asserting you're running apache with `www-data` user :

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/filemanager/
```

You may also have a look to the [configuration wiki page](https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/Filemanager-configuration-file) and [sample page](https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/Specify-user-folder%2C-configuration-cases).

> (also, the instructions request changing a file ../connectors/php/filemanager.config.php, which for the life of me, I cannot find. ../connectors/php/default.config.php exists but doesn't follow the instructions very well if I was to substitute that.)

Thanks for pointing this out. It is updated.

Comment: Have you try to specify manually the serveroot / fileroot path as explained here ? https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/Specify-user-folder%2C-configuration-cases

Comment: I've followed this advice: `Just copy the content of /scripts/filemanager.config.js.default into /scripts/filemanager.config.js and load the filemanager into your web browser, it should work.`, but have also changed them too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem arose when migrating a site from dedicated hosting with PHP 5.3 to shared hosting with PHP 5.4, all of a sudden the file manager started behaving as described by the original poster. I updated to the latest FileManger version (2.0.0-dev) but still the same.

A look at the server error log showed a fatal error in connectors/php/filemanager.class.php on line #1312 where require_once('./inc/vendor/wideimage/lib/WideImage.php') failed to open the file. Checking the path there is no "vendor" directory so I removed that from the path and the server error went away. But still the same loading graphic.

I then considered that PHP 5.4.x wants to have the TimeZone set and depending on the server configuration may throw warnings or errors, even fatal ones in the background. So I added date_default_timezone_set ('America/Toronto'); at the top of the file connectors/php/filemanager.php and after that everything worked perfect. This may not be the optimal solution but it worked for me. If you try it of course change the TimeZone to your own.

This one had me pulling my hair out for a while, hope it helps someone.